# Are there any errors in my proof for "prove [(p→q)∧(q→r)]→(p→r) is a tautology"?

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus, solution-verification

Please help me be 100% sure that there are no errors in this proof. I am especially worried that I applied a rule incorrectly or dropped parenthesis when it was inappropriate. This proof thing is very new to me. Thanks a lot! 
$$[(p\implies q)\land(q\implies r)]\implies(p\implies r)$$
$$\equiv\neg[(\neg p\lor q)\land(\neg q\lor r)]\lor(\neg p\lor r)$$
because
$$p\implies q\equiv\neg p\lor q$$
$\neg(\neg p\lor q)\lor\neg(\neg q\lor r)\lor(\neg p\lor r)$ by DeMorgan's law.

$p\land \neg q\lor q\land \neg r\lor(\neg p\lor r)$ by De 
Morgan's law

$p\land \neg q\lor q\land\neg r\lor(r\lor \neg p)$by Commutative law

$p\land\neg q\lor q\land(\neg r\lor r)\lor\neg p$ by Associative law

$p\land
T\land T\lor\neg p$ by Negation law

$p\lor\neg p \equiv 1$ by Identity law

T by Negation law

$$Q.E.D$$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Thanks. I feel like its readable enough as is. I will be sure to learn MathJax for future posts.

Comment: @zwim so I cannot just use associative law to go from ¬r ∨ (r ∨ ¬p) to (¬r ∨ r) ∨ ¬p? EDIT:zwim deleted his response ?

Comment: If you had put correct parenthesis, you'll see you have $PQ' + QR' + P' + R$ and you go to $PQ' + Q(R'+R) + P'$ you can see it develops to a term in $QR$ you do not have.

Comment: @zwim so, I cannot drop the parenthesis after De'Morgans law is applied? Where do I make my first mistake with the parenthesis?

Comment: I added correct parenthesing to your solution, can you now see the problem ?

Comment: @zwim, thank you. to make sure i understand, De Morgan's does not allow me to drop the parenthesis?

Comment: It is exactly like $p\land q=PQ$ and $p\lor q=P+Q$ in arithmetic. You can drop parenthesis when the same operation is used, e.g. $P+Q+R=(P+Q)+R$ or $PQR=(PQ)R$ but if you mix symbols $(P+Q)R\neq P+QR$ but instead it distribute to $PR+QR$.

Comment: okay that makes sense. but after (p ∧ ¬q)∨ (q ∧ ¬r) ∨ (r ∨ ¬p ) I am completely unsure on how to proceed with the proof

Comment: @zwim Really that should be $P\vee Q=P+Q-PQ$, otherwise you'd have $1\vee 1 = 2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{array}{l}
((P\implies Q)\land(Q\implies R))\implies(P\implies R)\\\\
\bigg((P'+Q)\times(Q'+R)\bigg)\implies(P'+R) & \text{translate implications}\\\\
\bigg((P'+Q)\times(Q'+R)\bigg)'+(P'+R) & \text{translate overall implication}\\\\
(P'+Q)'+(Q'+R)'+(P'+R) & \text{negation of big parenthesis}\\\\
PQ'+QR'+P'+R & \text{negation of small parenthesis}\\\\
PQ'+QR'+1P'+ 1R & \text{introduce multiplication by 1}\\\\
PQ'+QR'+(Q+Q')P'+ (Q+Q')R & \text{replace 1 by tautology}\\\\
\color{red}{PQ'}+\color{green}{QR'}+ P'Q+ \color{red}{P'Q'} +\color{green}{QR}+ Q'R & \text{develop}\\\\
\color{red}{(P+P')Q'}+\color{green}{Q(R+R')}+ P'Q + Q'R & \text{factorize}\\\\
1Q'+1Q+ P'Q + Q'R & \text{replace tautology by 1}\\\\
Q'+Q+ P'Q + Q'R & \text{remove multiplication by 1}\\\\
(Q+ Q') + P'Q+Q'R & \text{associativity}\\\\
1 + P'Q+Q'R & \text{replace tautology by 1}\\\\
1 & \text{ replace 1+X by 1}
\end{array}$

The same written in logic formalism:

$\begin{array}{l}
((p\implies q)\land (q\implies r))\implies(p\implies r)\\
((\lnot p\lor q)\land (\lnot q\lor r))\implies(\lnot p\lor r)\\
\lnot ((\lnot p\lor q)\land (\lnot q\lor r)) \lor (\lnot p\lor r)\\
\lnot (\lnot p\lor q) \lor \lnot (\lnot q\lor r) \lor (\lnot p\lor r)\\
(p\land \lnot q) \lor (q\land \lnot r) \lor \lnot p \lor r\\
(p\land \lnot q) \lor (q\land \lnot r) \lor (\tau\land \lnot p) \lor (\tau\land  r)\\
(p\land \lnot q) \lor (q\land \lnot r) \lor ((q\lor \lnot q)\land \lnot p) \lor ((q\lor \lnot q)\land r)\\
\color{red}{(p\land \lnot q)} \lor \color{green}{(q\land \lnot r)} \lor (\lnot p\land q) \lor \color{red}{(\lnot p\land \lnot q)} \lor \color{green}{(q\land r)}\lor (\lnot q\land r)\\
\color{red}{((p\lor \lnot p)\land \lnot q)} \lor \color{green}{(q\land (r\lor \lnot r))} \lor (\lnot p\land q) \lor (\lnot q\land r)\\
(\tau\land  \lnot q) \lor (\tau\land q) \lor (\lnot p\land q) \lor (\lnot q\land r)\\
\lnot q \lor q \lor (\lnot p\land q) \lor (\lnot q\land r)\\
(q\lor \lnot q) \lor (\lnot p\land q) \lor (\lnot q\land r)\\
\tau \lor (\lnot p\land q) \lor (\lnot q\land r)\\
\tau\end{array}$

Comment: Okay this is very helpful. But I am still not understanding something important.  If I have the distributive property (p ∨( q ∧ r))=(p ∨ q) ∧ (p ∨ r), and I replace like (p+(qr)) and let p=1, q=2, r=3, i get 7, but if I do (p+q)(p+r) i get 12. What am i not understanding here about the relationship between arithmetic language and the propositonal calculus symbols?

Comment: @brettF The propositions are truth values, so they're either true ($1$) or false ($0$). This is why zwim has used $T=1$ since it is always true. The benefit of turning propositional logic into arithmetic is that we can express connectives with simple, calculable algebraic expressions, e.g., $P\wedge Q$ becomes $P\times Q$, which you can see is true with the truth table $(0\times0=0,\ldots)$.

Comment: Personally, I'd opt for normal logical symbols when writing the proof, since it's easier to see how each line is related to the previous one. But arithmetic language is quite good for checking.

Comment: @Jam but could you explain why the  distributive property (p ∨( q ∧ r))=(p ∨ q) ∧ (p ∨ r) does not hold when numbers(like 1,2,3) are substituted in?

Comment: @brettF It holds when $p,q,r$ are either $0$ or $1$ and is equivalent to the arithmetic expression $p+\left(q\times r\right)-p\times \left(q\times r\right) = (p+q-p\times q)\times (p+r-p\times r)$. Indeed, it's not true for values like $0.5$ or $2$ but we're only interested in $0$ or $1$ since there's only two truth values: true and false. There's no "true version 2".

Comment: Or alternatively, you can do it like zwim mentioned in another comment, where you say all even numbers correspond to 'false' and all odd numbers correspond to 'true'. But this is getting a bit tangential now compared to the original logic question.

Comment: I removed the comment is was wrong. In fact it is not "real" addition or multiplication, just consider it a symbol replacement.

Comment: @jam okay thank you so much, this is starting to make a lot more sense to me. how do i know whether to sub in 1 or 0 for p when checking? because we dont know if p is true or false to begin with. should the expression work for all combinations of 1 and 0? is that the idea?

Comment: @brettF Yes, that's exactly it. When we view a logical formula with its [truth table](https://miro.medium.com/max/1310/1*MCO7lGwuIJxbmvRIXjrJoQ.png), we see that it is essentially a function of arguments $P,Q$ that evaluates to the entries in the right hand column. But a tautology should evaluate to true, $T=1$, for all inputs, so a tautological formula should be arithmetically equal to $1$ for all $0,1$ values of $P,Q$. It's not necessarily easier to do it arithmetically but it's good for plugging into a computer to verify it.

Comment: @zwim do you have any advice on how to recognize when it is time to multiply by 1?

Answer (score 2):

Your use of delimiters seems a bit janky to me. See if you can follow this line of reasoning:

\begin{align}
\Omega
&\equiv [(p\to q)\land(q\to r)]\to(p\to r) & (\text{for brevity})\\[0.5em]
&\equiv \neg(\neg p\lor q)\lor\neg(\neg q\lor r)\lor(\neg p\lor r)\\[0.5em]
&\equiv (p\land\neg q)\lor(q\land\neg r)\lor(\neg p\lor r)\\[0.5em]
&\equiv \bigl\{[(p\land\neg q)\lor q]\land[(p\land\neg q)\lor\neg r]\bigr\}\lor(\neg p\lor r)\\[0.5em]
&\equiv [(p\lor q)\land(p\lor\neg r)\land(\neg q\lor\neg r)]\lor(\neg p\lor r)\\[0.5em]
&\equiv (p\lor q\lor\neg p\lor r)\land(p\lor\neg r\lor\neg p\lor r)\land(\neg q\lor\neg r\lor\neg p\lor r)\\[0.5em]
&\equiv \mathbf{T}\land\mathbf{T}\land\mathbf{T}\\[0.5em]
&\equiv \mathbf{T}.
\end{align}

Comment: That is working fine too, full use of distributing stuff.